# Code and data for FAO/GAEZ crop suitability

Tags: agriculture

Is the underlying data and code used to construct the crop suitability measures from the FAO/GAEZ (http://gaez.fao.org) available anywhere? Or for any similar crop suitability measures?

Comment: [This document](http://www.fao.org/fileadmin/user_upload/gaez/docs/GAEZ_Model_Documentation.pdf) contains some tables and links to xlsx files. I guess, to these: http://webarchive.iiasa.ac.at/Research/LUC/GAEZv3.0/docs/ You could also ask at FAO-GAEZ@fao.dot.org or inf@iiasa.ac.at